# DateTimeOffset ParseExact

Tags: c#

i have to parse csv with date (i know those date are utc).

```
 20200102 07:00:12:342
```

in my method i ParseExact them like this.

```
   DateTimeOffset utcTime1 = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(csv[0].Trim(), "yyyyMMdd  HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,  DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
```

but result isnt utc but my thread time.

```
1/2/2020 7:11:43 AM +01:00
1/2/2020 7:11:45 AM +01:00
1/2/2020 7:11:46 AM +01:00
1/2/2020 7:11:46 AM +01:00
1/2/2020 7:11:47 AM +01:00
```

so i tried this:

```
 DateTimeOffset utcTime1 = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(csv[0].Trim(), "yyyyMMdd  HH:mm:ss:zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,  DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```

but it throw an error invalid datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have provided wrong format string for milliseconds in the second one (`zzz`, which is offset from UTC). [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings):

> "fff"  The milliseconds in a date and time value.

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("20200102 07:00:12:342", "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,  DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal)
```

Parses to `02-Jan-20 7:00:12 AM +00:00` on my machine.

Comment: wow it seem i add just a 2 space between dd and HH compared your cast it work now thank fff was not working nether

Comment: @Zwan was glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the input format that is mentioned in the second one `"yyyyMMdd  HH:mm:ss:zzz"`

`zzz` stands for hours and minutes offset from UTC.

But you are actually having the value of milliseconds there, which should be the specified by `fff`.

So your correct format should be `"yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss:fff"`.

```
    DateTimeOffset utcTime1 = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("20200102 07:00:12:342", "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,  DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
    Console.WriteLine(utcTime1);
```

This gave me

`1/2/2020 7:00:12 AM +00:00`

Comment: yes main problem is prolly i was forced use allowWhiteSpace since my format was wrong